# setting the little app icon in a notification

Tags: java, android, notifications

I'm trying to build my notification and I can't find the option to show the little rounded app logo below the round app icon like in this image

[image]

How do I do it?

Comment: Have you tried using `setSmallIcon()` ? You can check this link >> https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setSmallIcon(int)

Comment: yes, it set the main round image, like the guy's profile picture on the example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone bumps into the same problem, mgcaguioa is right, it is with `setSmallIcon()` but in order for it to work you also need to set `setLargeIcon()`, hope this helps anyone